# error managing memory

Tags: linux, macos, memory, malloc, checksum

I have a error in my code. I become on mac a incorrect checksum for freed object and under Linux a malloc error. Can somebody help me?

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010, The PLDesktop Development Team
 *
 *  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 *  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 *  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 *  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
 *  Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 *  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 *  Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA
 *
 */
#ifndef PLBUFFER_H
#define PLBUFFER_H

#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 

namespace PLSDK {

/**
  * Buffer for all parts of data.
  *
  * @ingroup tools_core
  */
template
class PLBuffer : public virtual PLObject {
public:
   /**
     * Constructor.
     */
   PLBuffer() : PLObject(), m_capacity(0), m_count(0), m_data(0) {}
   /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param size The size of the buffer.
     */
   PLBuffer(pluint size);
   /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param b Element to add to the buffer.
     */
   PLBuffer(bufferT b);
   /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param b Data to set into the buffer.
     * @param len Length of the data.
     */
   PLBuffer(bufferT *b, pluint len);
   /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param b Buffer to copy.
     */
   PLBuffer(PLBuffer *b);
   /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param b Buffer to copy.
     */
   PLBuffer(const PLBuffer &b);
   /**
     * Destructor.
     */
   virtual ~PLBuffer();
   /**
     * Data from the buffer.
     *
     * @return Data from the buffer.
     */
   inline bufferT *data() const;
   /**
     * The size of the buffer.
     *
     * @return The size of the buffer.
     */
   inline pluint capacity() const;
   /**
     * How many parts are in the buffer.
     *
     * @return The number of parts that are in the buffer.
     */
   inline pluint count() const;
   /**
     * Is the buffer a empty buffer.
     *
     * @return True if the buffer is empty.
     */
   inline bool isEmpty() const;
   /**
     * Set the data as data from the buffer.
     * This delete all data that was set before.
     *
     * @param b Data to set.
     * @param len Length of the data to set.
     */
   inline void setBuffer(bufferT *b, pluint len);
   /**
     * Clear the buffer and delete all memory that was mapped for the buffer.
     */
   inline void clear();
   /**
     * Don't delete the mapped data but set the size to null. So we overright all
     * data.
     */
   inline void clean();
   /**
     * Set all data to null and than set the size to null. So no data was in the ram
     * and we don't remap data.
     */
   inline void secureClean();
   /**
     * Append one data at the end of the buffer.
     *
     * @param d Data to append;
     */
   inline void append(const bufferT d);
   /**
     * Append a array of data to the buffer.
     *
     * @param d Array of data.
     * @param len Length of the array of data.
     * @exception PLAppendEmptyElementException The length of the data are empty.
     */
   inline void append(const bufferT *d, pluint len) throw(PLAppendEmptyElementException);
   /**
     * Append a buffer of data to the buffer.
     *
     * @param d Array of data.
     * @exception PLAppendEmptyElementException The length of the data are empty.
     */
   inline void append(PLBuffer *d) throw(PLAppendEmptyElementException);
   /**
     * Append a buffer of data to the buffer.
     *
     * @param d Array of data.
     * @exception PLAppendEmptyElementException The length of the data are empty.
     */
   inline void append(const PLBuffer &d) throw(PLAppendEmptyElementException);
   /**
     * Cut data out of the buffer.
     *
     * @param s Start point to cut.
     * @param e End point to cut.
     * @return The data that we cut out of the buffer.
     * @exception PLEmptyElementException The returnd value was a empty value.
     */
   inline bufferT *cutData(pluint s, pluint e) throw(PLEmptyElementException);
   /**
     * Ends the data of the buffer with the data of another buffer?
     *
     * @param b Buffer to test.
     * @return True if the buffer ends with the data of the buffer b.
     */
   inline bool endsWith(PLBuffer *b);
   /**
     * Ends the data of the buffer with the data of another buffer?
     *
     * @param b Buffer to test.
     * @return True if the buffer ends with the data of the buffer b.
     */
   inline bool endsWith(const PLBuffer &b);
   /**
     * Get the data of a part from the buffer.
     *
     * @param s Startpoint of the part.
     * @param e Endpoint of the part.
     * @return The part of the buffer.
     */
   inline bufferT *data(pluint s, pluint e);
   /**
     * Return a buffer with a part of this buffer.
     *
     * @param s Start point in the buffer.
     * @param e End point in the buffer.
     * @return The buffer with the part of the buffer.
     */
   inline PLBuffer subPart(pluint s, pluint e);
   /**
     * Return the data at the point p.
     *
     * @param p Point for that you want the data.
     * @return The data at the position p.
     */
   inline bufferT dataAt(pluint p);
   /**
     * Return the first index of a component.
     *
     * @param c The component to search for.
     * @param s Start position to search for.
     * @return The first index of the component c.
     * @exception PLIndexOutOfRangeException The start position was out of range.
     * @exception PLElementNotFoundException The element was not found in the buffer.
     */
   inline int indexOf(bufferT c, pluint s = 0) throw(PLIndexOutOfRangeException, PLElementNotFoundException);
   /**
     * Return the first index of a buffer.
     *
     * @param c The buffer to search for.
     * @param s Start position to search for.
     * @return The first index of the component c.
     * @exception PLIndexOutOfRangeException The start position was out of range.
     * @exception PLElementNotFoundException The element was not found in the buffer.
     */
   inline int indexOf(PLBuffer c, pluint s = 0) throw(PLIndexOutOfRangeException, PLElementNotFoundException);
   /**
     * Insert a component at the position p.
     *
     * @param c The component to add.
     * @param p Position where to add the component.
     */
   inline void insertAt(bufferT c, pluint p);
   /**
     * Insert a component array at the position p.
     *
     * @param c The component array to add.
     * @param len The length of the component array.
     * @param p Position where to add the component.
     */
   inline void insertAt(bufferT *c, pluint len, pluint p);
   /**
     * Find the last position of c.
     *
     * @param c Component to search for.
     * @param s Start position to start for.
     * @return The last position of c.
     * @exception PLIndexOutOfRangeException The start position was out of range.
     * @exception PLElementNotFoundException The element was not found in the buffer.
     */
   inline int lastIndexOf(bufferT c, int s = -1) throw(PLIndexOutOfRangeException, PLElementNotFoundException);
   /**
     * Find the last position of c.
     *
     * @param c Component to search for.
     * @param s Start position to start for.
     * @return The last position of c.
     * @exception PLIndexOutOfRangeException The start position was out of range.
     * @exception PLElementNotFoundException The element was not found in the buffer.
     */
   inline int lastIndexOf(PLBuffer c, int s = -1) throw(PLIndexOutOfRangeException, PLElementNotFoundException);
   /**
     * Insert a component at the beginning of the buffer.
     *
     * @param c Component to add.
     */
   inline void prepend(bufferT c);
   /**
     * Insert a component at the beginning of the buffer.
     *
     * @param c Component to add.
     * @param len The length of the component.
     */
   inline void prepend(bufferT *c, pluint len);
   /**
     * Prepend a buffer of data to the buffer.
     *
     * @param d Array of data.
     */
   inline void prepend(PLBuffer *d);
   /**
     * Prepend a buffer of data to the buffer.
     *
     * @param d Array of data.
     */
   inline void prepend(PLBuffer d);
   /**
     * Remove a part of the buffer.
     *
     * @param s Startpoint for the delete part.
     * @param e Endpoint for the delete part.
     */
   inline void remove(pluint s, pluint e);
   /**
     * Array of components.
     *
     * @return The array of the components.
     */
   inline bufferT *array();
   /**
     * Write a component to the buffer.

     * It overright the existing component.
     *
     * @param p Position where to add the component.
     * @param c Component that you want to set.
     */
   inline void write(pluint p, bufferT c);
   /**
     * Write a component array to the buffer.

     * It overright the existing component.
     *
     * @param p Position where to add the component.
     * @param c Component array that you want to set.
     * @param len Length of the component array.
     */
   inline void write(pluint p, bufferT *c, pluint len);
   /**
     * Read the component from the position p.
     *
     * @param p Position of the component you want to read.
     * @return The component at the position p.
     */
   inline bufferT read(pluint p);
   /**
     * Read the component from the position p.
     *
     * @param p Position of the component you want to read.
     * @param len The length of the component you want to read.
     * @return The component at the position p.
     */
   inline bufferT *read(pluint p, pluint len);
   /**
     * Compare the buffer with another buffer data.
     *
     * @param data Buffer to compare to.
     * @return The compare result.
     */
   inline PLCompareResult compareTo(PLBuffer data);
   /**
     * Contains the buffer a value.
     *
     * @param value The value to test for a match for.
     * @return True if the buffer contains the value.
     */
   inline bool contains(bufferT value);
   /**
     * Contains the buffer another buffer data.
     *
     * @param data The data to test for a match for.
     * @param length The length of the data.
     * @return True if the buffer contains the buffer.
     */
   inline bool contains(bufferT *data, pluint length);
   /**
     * Replace the part replace with the part with in this buffer.
     *
     * @param replace Part to search for.
     * @param with Part to replace with.
     */
   inline void replaceAll(PLBuffer *replace, PLBuffer *with);
   /**
     * Operator for the direct access to the data.
     */
   inline bufferT operator[](int pos);
   /**
     * Compare the buffer.
     */
   inline bool operator == (PLBuffer data);
   /**
     * Compare the buffer.
     */
   inline bool operator != (PLBuffer data);
   /**
     * Is the buffer smaler than another buffer.
     */
   inline bool operator  data);
   /**
     * Is the buffer lager than another buffer.
     */
   inline bool operator > (PLBuffer data);
   /**
     * Copy the buffer.
     */
   inline PLBuffer &operator =(const PLBuffer &buffer);
protected:
   /**
     * Resize the buffer to the given size.
     *
     * @param c The size to resize to.
     */
   void resize(pluint c) {
      if(m_data == 0) {
         m_data = new bufferT[c];
         m_capacity = c;
         m_count = 0;
         return;
      }
      if(m_count + c > m_capacity) {
         bufferT *t = new bufferT[m_count + c];
         if(m_data != 0) {
            for(pluint i = 0 ; i 
PLBuffer::PLBuffer(pluint size) : PLObject(), m_data(0), m_capacity(0), m_count(0) {
   if(size > 0) {
      m_data = new bufferT[size];
      m_capacity = size;
   }
}

template
PLBuffer::PLBuffer(bufferT b) : PLObject(), m_capacity(1), m_count(1) {
   m_data = new bufferT[1];
   m_data[0] = b;
}

template
PLBuffer::PLBuffer(bufferT *b, pluint len)
   : PLObject(), m_data(0), m_capacity(len), m_count(len) {
   if(len > 0) {
      m_data = new bufferT[len];
      pluint i = 0;
      while(i 
PLBuffer::PLBuffer(PLBuffer *b) : PLObject(), m_data(), m_capacity(b->m_count), m_count(b->m_count) {
   if(b->m_count > 0) {
      m_data = new bufferT[b->m_count];
      pluint i = 0;
      if(b->m_data != 0) {
         while(i m_count) {
            m_data[i] = b->m_data[i];
            i++;
         }
      }
   }
}

template
PLBuffer::PLBuffer(const PLBuffer &b) : PLObject(), m_data(0), m_capacity(b.m_count), m_count(b.m_count) {
   if(b.m_count > 0) {
      m_data = new bufferT[b.m_count];
      pluint i = 0;
      if(b.m_data != 0) {
         while(i 
PLBuffer::~PLBuffer() {
   if(m_data != 0) {
      delete m_data;
      m_data = 0;
   }
}

template
bufferT *PLBuffer::data() const {
   return m_data;
}

template
pluint PLBuffer::capacity() const {
   return m_capacity;
}

template
pluint PLBuffer::count() const {
   return m_count;
}

template
bool PLBuffer::isEmpty() const {
   return m_count == 0;
}

template
void PLBuffer::setBuffer(bufferT *b, pluint len) {
   delete m_data;
   m_data = b;
   m_capacity = len;
   m_count = len;
}

template
void PLBuffer::clear() {
   delete m_data;
   m_data = 0;
   m_capacity = 0;
   m_count = 0;
}

template
void PLBuffer::clean() {
   m_count = 0;
}

template
void PLBuffer::secureClean() {
   for(int i = 0 ; i 
void PLBuffer::append(const bufferT d) {
   resize(1);
   m_data[m_count] = d;
   m_count++;
}

template
void PLBuffer::append(const bufferT *d, pluint len) throw(PLAppendEmptyElementException) {
   if(len 
void PLBuffer::append(PLBuffer *d) throw(PLAppendEmptyElementException) {
   if(d->count() m_data, d->m_count);
}

template
void PLBuffer::append(const PLBuffer &d) throw(PLAppendEmptyElementException) {
   if(d.count() 
bufferT *PLBuffer::cutData(pluint s, pluint e) throw(PLEmptyElementException) {
   if(e - s == 0) {
      PL_EXCEPTION(PLEmptyElementException);
   }
   if(e >= m_count) {
      e = m_count - 1;
   }
   if(e > s) {
      plSwap(e, s);
   }
   bufferT *ret = data(s, e);
   remove(s, e);
   return ret;
}

template
bool PLBuffer::endsWith(PLBuffer *b) {
   if(m_count - 1 - b->m_count m_count - 1;
   for(int i = m_count - 1 ; i >= m_count - 1 - b->m_count ; i--) {
      if(m_data[i] != b->m_data[j]) {
         return false;
      }
      j--;
   }
   return true;
}

template
bool PLBuffer::endsWith(const PLBuffer &b) {
   return endsWith(&b);
}

template
bufferT *PLBuffer::data(pluint s, pluint e) {
   if(e (e, s);
   }
   if(e - s == 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   if(e > m_count) {
      e = m_count;
   }
   bufferT *ret = new bufferT[e - s];
   for(pluint i = 0 ; i 
PLBuffer PLBuffer::subPart(pluint s, pluint e) {
   return PLBuffer(data(s, e), e - s);;
}

template
bufferT PLBuffer::dataAt(pluint p) {
   if(p 
int PLBuffer::indexOf(bufferT c, pluint s) throw(PLIndexOutOfRangeException, PLElementNotFoundException) {
   if(s >= m_count) {
      PL_EXCEPTION(PLIndexOutOfRangeException);
   }
   for(pluint i = s ; i 
int PLBuffer::indexOf(PLBuffer c, pluint s) throw(PLIndexOutOfRangeException, PLElementNotFoundException) {
   if(s + c.m_count > m_count) {
      PL_EXCEPTION(PLIndexOutOfRangeException);
   }
   for(pluint i = s ; i 
void PLBuffer::insertAt(bufferT c, pluint p) {
   resize(1);
   for(pluint i = m_count - 1 ; i >= p ; i--) {
      m_data[i + 1] = m_data[i];
   }
   m_data[p] = c;
   m_count++;
}

template
void PLBuffer::insertAt(bufferT *c, pluint len, pluint p) {
   resize(len);
   int i;
   for(i = m_count - 1; i >= p ; i--) {
      if(i 
int PLBuffer::lastIndexOf(bufferT c, int s) throw(PLIndexOutOfRangeException, PLElementNotFoundException) {
   if(s = m_count) {
      PL_EXCEPTION(PLIndexOutOfRangeException);
   }
   for(pluint i = s ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
      if(m_data[i] == c) {
         return i;
      }
   }
   PL_EXCEPTION(PLElementNotFoundException);
}

template
int PLBuffer::lastIndexOf(PLBuffer c, int s) throw(PLIndexOutOfRangeException, PLElementNotFoundException) {
   if(s = m_count) {
      PL_EXCEPTION(PLIndexOutOfRangeException);
   }
   for(pluint i = s ; i > c.count() ; i--) {
      for(pluint j = 0 ; j > c.count() ; j++) {
         if(m_data[i + j] != c.m_data[j]) {
            break;
         }
         if(j == 0) {
            return i;
         }
      }
   }
   PL_EXCEPTION(PLElementNotFoundException);
}

template
void PLBuffer::prepend(bufferT c) {
   insertAt(c, 0);
}

template
void PLBuffer::prepend(bufferT *c, pluint len) {
   insertAt(c, len, 0);
}

template
void PLBuffer::prepend(PLBuffer *d) {
   prepend(d->m_data, d->m_count);
}

template
void PLBuffer::prepend(PLBuffer d) {
   prepend(d.m_data, d.m_count);
}

template
void PLBuffer::remove(pluint s, pluint e) {
   pluint diff = e - s;
   if(diff == 0) {
      return;
   }
   if(diff (e, s);
      diff = e - s;
   }
   if(e > m_count) {
      e = m_count;
   }
   for(pluint i = s ; i 
bufferT *PLBuffer::array() {
   bufferT *b = new bufferT[m_count];
   for(pluint i = 0 ; i 
void PLBuffer::write(pluint p, bufferT c) {
   if(p >= m_count) {
      resize(p - m_count);
   }
   m_data[p] = c;
}

template
void PLBuffer::write(pluint p, bufferT *c, pluint len) {
   if(p + len >= m_count) {
      resize(p + len - m_count);
   }
   for(pluint i = 0 ; i 
bufferT PLBuffer::read(pluint p) {
   return dataAt(p);
}

template
bufferT *PLBuffer::read(pluint p, pluint len) {
   return data(p, len);
}

template
PLCompareResult PLBuffer::compareTo(PLBuffer data) {
   if(m_count == data.m_count) {
      for(pluint i = 0 ; i  data.m_data[i]) {
            return PLCompareResultBigger;
         }
      }
      return PLCompareResultSame;
   }
   return PLCompareResultSmaller;
}

template
void PLBuffer::replaceAll(PLBuffer *replace, PLBuffer *with) {
   for(int i = 0 ; i m_data[0]) {
         for(int j = 0 ; j m_count ; j++) {
            if(i + j > m_count) {
               return;
            }
            if(j == replace->m_count - 1 && m_data[i + j] != replace->m_data[j]) {
               remove(i, i + replace->m_count - 1);
               insertAt(with->m_data, with->m_count - 1, i);
            } else if(m_data[i + j] != replace->m_data[j]) {
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

template
bool PLBuffer::contains(bufferT value) {
   for(int i = 0 ; i 
bool PLBuffer::contains(bufferT *data, pluint length) {
   int j;
   for(int i = 0 ; i 
bufferT PLBuffer::operator[](int pos) {
   return m_data[pos];
}

template
bool PLBuffer::operator == (PLBuffer data) {
   return compareTo(data) == PLCompareResultSame;
}

template
bool PLBuffer::operator != (PLBuffer data) {
   return compareTo(data) != PLCompareResultSame;
}

template
bool PLBuffer::operator  data) {
   return compareTo(data) == PLCompareResultSmaller;
}

template
bool PLBuffer::operator > (PLBuffer data) {
   return compareTo(data) == PLCompareResultBigger;
}

template
PLBuffer &PLBuffer::operator =(const PLBuffer &b) {
   if(m_data == 0) {
      delete m_data;
   }
   m_data = new bufferT[b.m_count];
   m_capacity = b.m_count;
   m_count = b.m_count;
   pluint i = 0;
   if(b.m_data != 0) {
      while(i
```

Can somebody help me? All code you can find under http://code.google.com/p/pldesktop/

Comment: Please try to trace the error to its source and post only the relevant snippet. This is not a free code auditing site.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code under `valgrind` on Linux - that should take you straight to the bug.